# base64 too large, mobile upload to API

Tags: javascript, html, api, mobile, aws-lambda

I have a web page, it works uploading images on PC, but when I want to take a photo from my phone and then uploading it, it doesnt work at all. I'm just working with JS and HTML, using the "input type=file" to upload or take the photos. Can someone could help me please, I'm working on Amazon Lambda.

I dont know if the picture taken by my phone is too large or what, but on the Cloudwatch, the base64 turns massive!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("input[type=file]").click(function () {
        $(this).val("");
      });

    $("input[type=file]").change(function () {

        var files = document.getElementById('upload-photo').files;
        if (files.length > 0) {
          getBase64(files[0]);
          $("#cargando").show();
        }

        function getBase64(file) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          reader.onload = function (e) {


          var dataURL = e.target.result,
          c = document.querySelector('canvas'), // see Example 4
          ctx = c.getContext('2d'),
          img = new Image();

          img.onload = function() {
            c.width = "500px";
            c.height = "500px";
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          };

          img.src = c.toDataURL('image/jpeg',0.1);

            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "https://signature.ivy-company.cloud/decoders/webapi",
              dataType: 'json',
              contentType: 'application/json',
              headers: {
                "ivy-token": '6ct0dc7f-4t3c-419f-970a-424thce052cb',
                "ivy-method": 'start-request-ocr',
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
              }....
```

 20:49:12 START RequestId: 786fbef1-671d-4354-844d-f8e8caf38983 Version: $LATEST 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 2019-09-17T20:49:13.021Z 786fbef1-671d-4354-844d-f8e8caf38983 {"resource":"/decoders/webapi","path":"/decoders/webapi","httpMethod":"POST","headers":{"accept":"application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"es-US,es-419;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6","content-type":"application/json","Host":"signature.ivy-movistar.cloud","ivy-method":"st 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 0Fq5Dk/eSIY2CKi5G4A8+n+enFXIrxmVkWKFcvktKeM44oQ2Me6ty6Fy+FjwWxwW7/wD1+tP2j5wk7RHeCJB+f48c8Y4pp2YlYru+XlRZm+dQCCB+WPWmmcyFkjDKIxtMYGc89T0yOP09qQE+9pFMghiRLcfMN33vpVG+zcIqQKvnRgeWQpGeOR/OtouzRM9j85/FlzMv7SvwztrySGKP7dcXMd48nzyTBGBQemFJbPH+H6N667Nr17M0cYU2ccl3MW6M6gnP4k/0rvx+sYvyM4XuMsLl8DzV42ZVwmM56EGrDTSeZGD8oQ/6pvT3Pt/KvLs2wejB1k8pkafagbcFk7+mPQ+/1qxarEQXba0hH7wg/l9QeOlItbjrmSRXgLJ86g7ducEn/wCt+VV 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 o4bZI0wQv3tqZ6r6/8A66rSK6tKSoyoCyKHwcdv/wBfShCtoWfNMyspIljiT9yWQ7lP+SaopJdo8Ygjib5CJBM+FGfU+v1rJJWHH4jSMrhAZI5BLPHg4Azjtx/nFQSNI6rH5QS5AOXXrs/vY7+lDi7ji7FWOW4DZeMiEuGVpD95R3qxOtzIWMfmKsjdcf54+tTawDmDxwJC6lmZDulRueew/wA/41WFu0KrKsMktyvy5kOUAPTA9vxPSrjoxbLQWSP7HbSTFg9w86rBDv5PPJz2xj6V8B/G7U9M1T4g+FdNv9InvvEF74whfS7GCXZHZW8TfvJ5T6gLhUxljjpiu3CRlzEy+E+uNNuLWeeR1E8bCJFliRyW5GPmFdhaW8gErwzJ5af8fDTpgFf7u 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 2R7VZZC339+ACegI/z2oE9GChY3aN1VcjgP057k9+ppZREIvLDRIXGNoGOex70o3DdFIbhhmYKhGFL8fjUyOhQ+TIyjbiaRs4UD73+etJaoNmRMWY4Ej7SN0JEfzAAf8A6+OvSmrJK52yGUZG8g8Z/wA9e2KpLQN2WtjKyBo9pchlI5OO4Ydj9anRZch5CZFZfl8roo9vfpWbV5F63J7a2EjMQwXCbmdWzuGex9atXRiW3THCxt++lLdf84FO0nYGzNjxMl15KjfkbflG4g+n51LFGysscbMwIG5GPcdiPz4oXKh3tEt3H72OEwCRZFH7x8A/j9KgjgmSN41uFSYPuKiMHPqAR6fWjohJaDXhjmxIYgZd3zKh4J9KqJExZpNkjhmIMan+npz/APq 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 habauRkdj+XSuh+GimfwNoks8cZI3x2YhB5UEEH8Mj0zXRJ3omcX77O9jQxrlV8yUcSPwMewH6Z6dfSlmkYMoMSKFXb5e3gcd/1rlSsbRvcVYiyE4ZUZflcdF9f51btxuw0zSyRqpSSK3HzSNjgD0B7n0/Onua8yuW44Io0jYMDKU3E7ePofX0+tVZFMgbYN4DYMaDHHYL+FCVh3I1twhlYuHiQDaO4HuO/4HvU8s84VTEVRFjG4hzjOf0oexMrXQ+2TMkUTTsmXywK9R6A1krme6ZGYOktx+43HnP179OntT6kSLAVoXeNC7MrHaGA59/b/IqGMbWJwFCHiMjIY+nsaa3Js0iLDbEaRMPM370MeFXPHBpJIMtNDHDIFdh5jZxle5B/zntVx+Mcn 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 SJxFFFGSIxjliPzraDvNGdS3KeK/s1K2njxBpcY8mS5v5rmSXH+sMrAliPc8DHQCvqMPGZXK7Yp3TE4iHJI7n/wCtV4xWkOm9DaiVpJQIm2TIP3hz8qqO/wD9arqRtmMEyptP71h39Bg1wFk0bss80UP3dnJY4OMdN3504+TJIkbrHI6p8zt+mR/npSuA944vlVWiI3bTnoPc/wA6hPkR4d0VgrYiEfOP8/pQtQI3UXUsJljSIOf45fmx6E//AFqnuYLZMBVJdM/Lxg8f/rwaYFAHZh+ARx8uTtGfSoxGcyH5nDvwVHB554oAjFtGxcO25t+XG0dOw+lKLRYwW27V25LgfmTWsdUAKGeL94VeNmGCF/yeh7VwvxI0/wC0+FNZWUF1mt3ERkPBOw7 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 U9kU53FSBk8A9PWqMNx4olnGdXImeQtI865UsTyD/npVqNgLNzrOtyAmZ4/NhIEpRSqHHp/nrz7Un9vzWUbF3ZlcEzjB4PcnNapaCbsjRsNSnvZBIHADLujITjHf8frXlnxst7i88BatYpbNNfNBL5cMYJZt0Z2cfl6V04VNTMq0vcM79nK2MnwwaBfs92dGvEhvDDc7gkkY2vHgdSCwzwCOPUV9B2MEZjNukIVpn/f3gb7qAcBfc469eKMTZ1GVSbcC4sMm3zNxI/iLjGMdT9aRYAjE4dwz5Vmbj35rj1NCPzC0wTJMQJ2syYO0d8dqlMjvsgV8owz8y4/EiiwDZRmOMSL5nmkEIOoGf73tWdc/ZbxJRLHyMlQG449B+HUVSeo92cheWL2sZNmj 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 MSAR+WfxpxaQEYRPmUEqH/hHXiqst1JGwZVjUIpEETAcHszevbj6VorEu9mcVqXj220iST+0LlolZwC7REpn0C4/Ef/rrzD4vftAeFfhB4G1D4j6/cPfXZJi8KaRCwEl5d7fkVQevUey9SQKpxtEhNs+WP2Yf2Z9T/aC8Yt+0T+0jeSET3P2rRPDWdwjjDb4reMHHIyMsw4PzHkKq/rbdiFLeOzt9PhsNLgiQadp1txDFEvCqo/m3UmueW5cnZFSOOSWXylUFVAJVcAk9iK+CfjveTaf8bfh5dvFHcPYeKNzFJRkRsPLJIxyPmH5V34Vav0MazTSPuKVLef7HIMJ9ojSSQSHADY7nqev5VA0ljGI4ZJWL7sLKF446fgea5ZqXOzdbIzwIA7qxaQB 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 1yIJodRuok2zruLMAevpj3FdGIWhKSLv7ryw4iWXfI2W464wMfT/OaoyJ5hiC4YyMQxT+JhzzXIBYPnIZEL8MAd4IOB7H/P6UR20QEKyIjE79rq+Bj+8ff29qSVim7oYJrhLiNYhmN0OFAHQ9j/ADrRl2xhliJJVRvZ2wBxz/nNJ3uJSsijFPlpIpImYquTK4wMH05pZHnB8oowSYYdrc/MF/ur6f8A66GkVLZEc81z5gEaGJc/MocDC+hHX8axdRETCCCcgmN2w0gzg4459uauPxE3sjzy+8K6fqjSx3Oy6juGJYSpkDB+8Pp/npWhYeB9C0y0aWytLRDJhJXjtxvf1Ofx7+tbt2EbcelNaW0MVr5MBUcm5cr5rE5Oz3A5+lfKvxstlj8T+EElZ 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 ZcvtDAYyQOgH51njPjLptOJqB3V4xIhEkkWISG7/T6dvWoGt3WYAzERMhV493f/PtXFuWWJGLCGGMKJFHO1cjHqff+dS+bKNzbpBH0ARRj6/pQ0kgTtIY9ypt2jReJkxMjrjHPGKkVJVJRmPk78Kf7uB/n8aXKwHTxwoC6QYDMAWLDOMdAfyqu/lRpG/lcSyfK3PHvUR1kBVaVUTYoUbRhX3deePxrzXxT4mk0cK8dhcXjpIEihtgMkk8bt2P84rpi2TK5TtYNa1i3Y6jbzaYjyf6OsN0GleP0IHHrxk/Wp5vDptrdllje4SR/kW6iGcdiCO4roikmRU0Rymt6Lqllbzahpr3U7QTIbmFEywUtwR/LPH1HWvij4hW9zp37Rvw11rWiV0143ttNiE 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 zOfEayR+iCSxT2tjNcfIbmygfehzuG0Y59R6VYdrfA2BpEPO8Lg89OK48Qv3rN6d2kOhfygzDDgt8oc8/X3H8qjESh8OyFsscrjaPbNYFdSC5aVsNtZXcru2jIC4/zzUYh8rO91CE87WyeRx9R0+lN7AnqSrFGSrDemQMAk84/pT2xCcjaTIVBPp7+1HQEMlDGSIAsiMcl3Tp7D/PFLPKJGMMb7/MYgKwwM+oPc+4x3oW4itPPFZQLJuYSKeFC5IH/1+ay4/EtvFiXecA5y6A8+wrdXYram3b6xa3Y3xzhnY5kt8EH/ACPWpr1TJHuDhFRPmXae/Xmm1ZgzmvD89xekwTZeKO/PlJjB4bA/z/kfnv8AtE3n9n/tOfDWG6jVbYa/LgghlJcfIQfw9 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 uvh9o0R3RxvZWr7Cp2/6voP8AP8q+gtsaqiIVkQNng5+b/HnpWdVO43rIHklkJf5csTuGO2OOKplpVRDIqkB8Epzx3z9ce1ZlL3kWFLSLHcqoCq+1gi9PbBqGVEi2jLgvL86pnGBnoaCr3M9kt7h4vMSRA7HBTnp3q1BoumBws97LGs33MJnGM9vzouKSGzLHZSl0V5oS37p2bJPplef/ANf0p5MFw6vuLrtw5Vfue9TqKLVxHcMogd0UswxKq9ffH9apvsttxmc7d+GCgcepFVsKTuRNOsxENmGSLdy07jJHt6dqnWK0iZ49xYlcJGx4z6/ypI0S0KkUcLS/JF+7D5Qx8bj/AIV8wftDWcmzRpY40H2HUUeWNVyWTrx6c4/z068LrURE2uU9ztk 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 GtDfksrmBUE0MiFo1ZWKn+IZDfTn8c1IF8tllYbiqbnEnAHrj+lZPcdyZ4pblPKhURzqN6P5f3UPqPfHSrEULiFENtNHKxG6NVJH+fr2oTDcuR2nmvFuTZONxPmDaTgdPx/X2xTkhnCZS2llaNvvRxH5VPr/jyaS3ArzKLcAywtGG/1kexs4Pt+VWrUyXML/ZY7mOETN8zQEA4GSfwAo6AZ0+omzaV2ACxD52K/pz/9bmsebx/Pbbf7Jht5JkUqHjtfMOD168Z9elPUDFuPFt3HIkCWz4f5naaM/eP9c+3FXLbXmnRZbiJ2jV/3ssAPAz/THX2pxQ7i65qCXemXSaNpssMcNqwuL+c/Kq8ZbHYdvfpXyl+z9qTXHxY8f6EA5uXvXIFtH+8XfETHn 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 96xgCVnIUj5h9B6/XpVbysSeZHHFIjKMmUnkj3/DjFAJ6sz7x90IkeMyOoIRM7en+1/k1i7R5jXtzayvbwvuLr+QyT+FVHRmc9T45/adv4X026vWyZ2voWtlJ+bduGBjv0J/AV758OrpR4esbcxgMlr/pBmz8j8c4r1J64ZHFF/vD1jTyxkScE4hUjeMEBT2B/P2rYnumZVKRRJHCpUvGMfMTzkV5J3QvYPLMaRKu5mlJ3SZHp0HceuagEUwysccgBA4Bx36AfhUpaaGslqeIsBPv8p1+zRP+7gkbpn72D19+e3elf/R5NnmbsQn5VBYj/Z/z1FfGWudqST+RSWUb1kiKp5eNuzn6/nVlESKOJY0JcBhDExPOT1BzyPbpVJ2Q3ErhlkkZSI0KLwF 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 EcLMqKAOWDtzz7etY4hP2jCk/cDzC80eZJUgRvlYdP+BH9KdLcuobe4MWMqyD9MVzySRp1Kst48oBaNSOOAuB7fjUHmCBGYBWWXrvXJOfb2rTRDPl79qwrZ/CO8uImeS7EN9Iu2TbwiDAH5Vz37GCWZ+FVha2iqJIkWWQOxLt5n3gPx+nBHpWMG1ID7IhQGWRFEk6BF2K/t1yPoPwqaQ3BUlkaGOYDYjgbjjuP8+npWkmrgM27QvzpvZRgDBx7Ef4monJdSI2O2XKu3mdPb+XSlG7F1EtJ5rdBJlo1Hy7WUYz04Pr/h7Ukql1Cyl92MgR8hvfjvV7IYwowXYW3iQgjYPmiz1BqjrOINJ1CaR1eNoNksif8ALPtn37/rmqhuhS2Pkj4aG20n4wazY 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 4G8SdXEgXHmp8w+VuSOvr9KO5L0TP52/gX5V1+1L4lg0154LIazBlmYmNC8jMzA9dp3kgDoPpx/SfejTreSxS0kL2ZsYzaMQAzr/eb3657elOUrNIIpFn7V5kKoh2AjqD1weoz/8AqqqxaSPBkeNGf53PRlPXnt1plF+RkwuxSmMbVQdR6D68/WlyUMhR2z0jG3Ck9jj/APXWd7TAliby0Z2l+eIYaJ+QoPXA9KXzA5f5x5LtwVXP4A/p+dVLWIEqPAUZCQqIcbNvQ+lII5pXcmQeWg+ZcYbA6GpiuYC2sKLhGliKFCQfMH1/zmonuNOj3TTXZIXICRc7vz5/z2q4pgZzeINLRNyErJCejJ1yP5/n3rEl8U2L3P2b7QkwlX5tsn8XYfhz9K0jFsh 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:13 3FCLCyTE8yR7DMyjGT7dcDoPrk06kVFpAWlgCRBEcmbGSgB7d81AQ2d85cKrAAHpj1P+etRFWAZKkxLblVVc5D+q9iR64xUtnbNdTR2ksIMVzOAX8zBGeMj34/T3p2A/Mb9o23uPjN+1b8N/gzakNoVnDDqfiExPn/RoVCwIexAK49cY6HFfqXFpem+EdKsPCvhiFLLT9O09I5p4UAZ5Aozk9uR9M89zWbu2BSEU0MDXG0ASngM3f1I79KijdZ2UmM4B+5IeS3vVO6AzPG0NtqnhPUbS9jEklpD+6jOGUKfvZHfqPpXyP8AsctcR2PxR0dVD2WieO721s0EhbZGmzGD68df8jRRuh9DoP2gLtYl0u+vsiC21u2WKdxhlw+Pl9Mkn04r6k+2mRNLZ 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:14 2019-09-17T20:49:14.201Z 786fbef1-671d-4354-844d-f8e8caf38983 body { "imgBuffer": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4URURXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAMAAABBAABAAAAIBAAAAEBBAABAAAAGAwAAA8BAgAIAAAArgAAABABAgAJAAAAtgAAABIBAwABAAAABgAAABoBBQABAAAAngAAABsBBQABAAAApgAAACgBAwABAAAAAgAAADEBAgAOAAAAwAAAADIBAgAUAAAAzgAAABMCAwABAAAAAQAAAGmHBAABAAAA4gAAAMIDAABIAAAAAQAAAEgAAAABAAAAc2Ftc3VuZwBTTS1KNDAwTQAASjQwME1VQlM0QlNHMQAy 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:14
+lTC78OeDy9u8Got4bhN4sWAGbJ2t+K7f89OhiWLyIXcMgk+VTL1yvJGe1c9RuMmbRd4oQlhvjjKO/beOcHqRSeeJFlFxkuEOfmz0/mDjt6VlZmiTJTueNWkQpExA8x+Dxzgfr1pbci4lkgZjuJygbAHA4FS1dDS90eQGUv8gWT7655B9TjpnFQSRxrv2jyxI2Hy/cf5FJKyFHm6ED/NHHHOnLL+58tec9uO340kPlxmMzo6oy/K6H5h7e1DkDehIZIGZn/eGPdlRjDMB2+vXmkdH2l3YRs7DylPXnvj8D9aa2HGxWbE4eOB2+RSpzxkn/ADmpoHhtpYkeQzSKoxFFGec9gp4z1pJokjk2q8ixAMpkG4K5+XJ6A+3PP61yPjwS/wDCN6mVaKRXQe 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:14 PGTng+oNAuZE7rClwsKKXmdsuSpxx/ET2/rTBJHOseYf3Ubn5nH60BJ3RGIhAr3ADHZ2HU/561XIQSB3RkDD5mft7/TrxQRqhZBuKlFbyo0w5VuSPUVIvlxiEQDzEYjKAc+2f8aa3A4n4h29uvhW9j+xCbW7/wCWznml+S2i7sR35xgdSR2Ga8/+BWjXNha+JSIbe3mvL2Q3TecHJAABLFeOQi4XsMeldkdaTMlbnPcrcl/kjAaSBsIxX5WyemPXtVpA0iyPLJGCJMqWXPQdAPy4ritc12M9RIrEho1w2XYp8ij39zVsvtcLGS8hOWUDq3XmmxFYrHL8s7NGkh3TOjc7c8AemeBnrVp2aWSTJjht2hGxBgdOg9c0gdrEG2aV90iQx+dGu1w/THqP 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:14 bSkj7XjUSrITJKssk29vNAyB6Zq64WZJZF2Rw8BGUgndjggen+c15rspMvcy9qv+7YP5u7hhkkY9vcVO0Zlt5ZcNHKRlZM8kjsRSauCKsUudx8pmyBu2N8w9cVYDsW2quwbflKH5h9T1pbsRPGifvQzOrbMLIRjoOp+v8ASkkd55WW2bcGTJ3A/Mf73+FUr3AYsaFTnLEn5QxweO1WxGGIclX2w/LFHyMfy4/WknuXFXKNzHKdqSwxQ7nO6FDkc9wf881WLOTkbZQBhWZOo+nbNO5Asdu8ruWjXapLL8x6+g/z3qSG0ku5kjjhk+R/3rIBtJPTJ/pVJ2YHjPxqtob7wB4ms7hlW2ksnWZw5G3MbZA9/p/SuG/ZPnuJPg3B9p3xCG5WOOBh8mI2ZA 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:15 2019-09-17T20:49:15.860Z 786fbef1-671d-4354-844d-f8e8caf38983 Llego hasta aca { "Item": { "responsable": "Rocio Chicas / Alejandra Castro", "chatId": "6cc0dc7f-453c-419f-970a-424e1ce052cb", "fechaRegistro": "2019-03-11T06:00:00.000Z", "idVendedor": "WAPI_INBENTA", "estado": "A", "cargo": "Inbenta", "canal": "WebAPI" } } 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:16 2019-09-17T20:49:15.860Z 786fbef1-671d-4354-844d-f8e8caf38983 { imgBuffer: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4URURXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAMAAABBAABAAAAIBAAAAEBBAABAAAAGAwAAA8BAgAIAAAArgAAABABAgAJAAAAtgAAABIBAwABAAAABgAAABoBBQABAAAAngAAABsBBQABAAAApgAAACgBAwABAAAAAgAAADEBAgAOAAAAwAAAADIBAgAUAAAAzgAAABMCAwABAAAAAQAAAGmHBAABAAAA4gAAAMIDAABIAAAAAQAAAEgAAAABAAAAc2Ftc3VuZwBTTS1KNDAwTQAASjQwME1VQlM0QlNHMQAyMDE5OjA5O 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:16 y9u8Got4bhN4sWAGbJ2t+K7f89OhiWLyIXcMgk+VTL1yvJGe1c9RuMmbRd4oQlhvjjKO/beOcHqRSeeJFlFxkuEOfmz0/mDjt6VlZmiTJTueNWkQpExA8x+Dxzgfr1pbci4lkgZjuJygbAHA4FS1dDS90eQGUv8gWT7655B9TjpnFQSRxrv2jyxI2Hy/cf5FJKyFHm6ED/NHHHOnLL+58tec9uO340kPlxmMzo6oy/K6H5h7e1DkDehIZIGZn/eGPdlRjDMB2+vXmkdH2l3YRs7DylPXnvj8D9aa2HGxWbE4eOB2+RSpzxkn/ADmpoHhtpYkeQzSKoxFFGec9gp4z1pJokjk2q8ixAMpkG4K5+XJ6A+3PP61yPjwS/wDCN6mVaKRXQeagXO4L0GO 2019/09/17/[$LATEST]bf9f05f9832447cebeebb1975be7bde5  20:49:16 uZE7rClwsKKXmdsuSpxx/ET2/rTBJHOseYf3Ubn5nH60BJ3RGIhAr3ADHZ2HU/561XIQSB3RkDD5mft7/TrxQRqhZBuKlFbyo0w5VuSPUVIvlxiEQDzEYjKAc+2f8aa3A4n4h29uvhW9j+xCbW7/wCWznml+S2i7sR35xgdSR2Ga8/+BWjXNha+JSIbe3mvL2Q3TecHJAABLFeOQi4XsMeldkdaTMlbnPcrcl/kjAaSBsIxX5WyemPXtVpA0iyPLJGCJMqWXPQdAPy4ritc12M9RIrEho1w2XYp8ij39zVsvtcLGS8hOWUDq3XmmxFYrHL8s7NGkh3TOjc7c8AemeBnrVp2aWSTJjht2hGxBgdOg9c0gdrEG2aV90iQx+dGu1w/THqPwqyHyvmyq

Comment: clean that up, we don't need the dataurl. then readup on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob

Comment: `picture taken by my phone` - what's the resolution of the picture?

Comment: the picture is about to 4.3mb

Comment: but why do I need a Canvas @dandavis?